# How do I communicate from Docker Hub to Jenkins via web hook?

Tags: jenkins, docker, webhooks, dockerhub

There seem to be a lot of examples to poll GitHub but how can I poll Docker Hub and trigger a build based on that?

I've got a webhook set up in Docker Hub for my automated build but I can't see how to poll for it in Jenkins.

There seems to be this Jenkins plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/DockerHub+Plugin

But, as I understand it the plugin has been broken since an API change on Docker Hub.

**Update:**

It seems that the answer is to use the Trigger Builds Remotely option under Build Triggers however it fails due to anonymous not having build permissions. Then I switched to using this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin

So the URL becomes something like this: https://jenkinsserver.com/buildByToken/build?job=test&token=test

That works if I POST to that URL via a browser (even incognito) but not with cURL. I get:

```
$ curl -X POST https://jenkinsserver.com/buildByToken/build?job=test&token=test

<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/securityRealm/commenceLogin?from=%2FbuildByToken%2Fbuild%3Fjob%3Dtest'/><script>window.location.replace('/securityRealm/commenceLogin?from=%2FbuildByToken%2Fbuild%3Fjob%3Dtest');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>

Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>
```

However, I can get it to work via cURL if I do this:

```
curl -X POST https://user:token@jenkinsserver.com/buildByToken/build?job=test&token=test
```

But, Docker Hub doesn't like that URL...
[image]

What am I missing here? Am I even on the right track? If you are someone who triggers and Jenkins task from a Docker Hub webhook, how do you do it?

Comment: Have you read [the Jenkins REST API docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API), including the bits on how to authenticate as a particular Jenkins user? If the problems are just request format and not authenticating, then all the answers are on that page.

Comment: I believe I'm doing everything properly according to that. It seems like docker hub just doesn't support a URL that Jenkins understands that includes credentials. Do I just have to give build permissions to anonymous?

Comment: I doubt it.  I don't see you using curl's --user option, like one of the examples does (the file parameter one). Are you using it?

Comment: Yeah, I know what you are saying works. The format I'm using for curl (https://user:token@jenkinsserver.com/buildByToken/build?job=test&token=test) also works and if you drill down from the page you linked you will see that example as well. The problem is you can't do either of those things via Docker Hub. I also wasn't expecting that with the Build by Token plugin I would need to authenticate. I don't need to authenticate via an incognito browser but I do via curl, which seems odd.

Comment: I'm surprised that you didn't need to authenticate via the browser; if you have security enables in Jenkins, you should have to authenticate to do anything that isn't read-only.  But sorry, I don't think I can help with this one..

Comment: That surprises me too. Not sure what the deal is there. Anyway, thanks for trying :). The only option might be to switch to matrix authentication and give build permissions to the job in question to anonymous.

Comment: I have some questions about https://github.com/jenkinsci/dockerhub-plugin
This project seems to be exactly what I want, but it seems that this project is not being actively developed. Is there any other project that can do same/similar things?
My project currently fails to pull the docker image from DockerHub. I need to install docker on the Jenkins host, right? And also my image on DockerHub is private. How can I pull the image?

Comment: So when configure the Jenkins project, I need to enter the "Image ID" for the image that it will pull from DockerHub. However the whole point is that I want Jenkins to do some testing and then tell DockerHub it passed or not and then DockerHub can publish the image or not.
So is it possible to use the content of the WebHook that DockerHub sent to Jenkins to pull the image (which I believe is not published yet)?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is relevant yet, but the solution would be to invoke the url like this:
`http://user:token@jenkins:8080/job/my-job/build?token=secretToken`

Answer (score 0):

Words from the author:
development in this plugin is indeed dormant, but can resurrect at any time, especially with a concrete use-case. I created this plugin as a PoC when DockerHub hook were announced, but don't have a concrete usage of it to experiment further.
Feel free to contribute so the plugin can support your own usage.