# How to automate deployment of a Docker container using Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops

I am new to DevOps and trying to automate the deployment of a Docker container using Jenkins. Here is what I have done so far:

1. Created a Dockerfile that builds the image and runs the container.
2. Pushed the image to a Docker registry.
3. Configured a Jenkins job that pulls the image from the registry and
   runs the container on a remote server.

However, I want to automate this process further so that the Jenkins job automatically triggers when a new image is pushed to the registry. How can I achieve this?

I have researched and found out about webhooks, but I am not sure how to implement them in my Jenkins job. Can someone please guide me on how to set up this automation process?

Comment: `what I have done so far:` Are these two pipelines? Just do it from one pipeline. Create a docker, push it, then on a remote server pull and run. One pipeline.

Comment: There is a dedicated [devops.se] Stack Exchange site and that might be a more appropriate place to ask about setting up your CI system.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27912243/3730626) may help. If you are using Docker Hub as the image registry you can allow your Jenkins job to be triggered remotely with a call to its REST API and go to the web hooks section of your image in DokcerHub and specify this endpoint in here.